# does android.permission.CAMERA can activate camera even when app is not open?

Tags: android, privacy, privacy-policy

When I go to the descitption of a certain app that have `android.permission.CAMERA` in application inspector it says : "...to take photos and videos at anytime"

I find it confusing and would like to know if anytime refers to anytime when the app is active i.e. open, or any time like it can activate it self in a background process and access the mentioned device.

The only doc i could find is https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/usage-notes but it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to take pictures/videos without showing the preview. But it is complicated depending on the android version. There is even a libary which handles it:

[android-hidden-camera](https://github.com/kevalpatel2106/android-hidden-camera)